# magento redirect payment method‎ to 3rd Party page

Tags: php, magento, checkout

i'm still trying to integrate this with my webshop, what i'm want to do is redirect the customer to the bank page, where he/she will enter all the data for tha payment(credit card number, secure code, etc), then he/she will be redirect to my web and here is where my problem begins, if the transaction fails for some reason, i don't whant to save the order, because it implies cleaning up the shoping cart and all the progress untill now, but if the transaction complete successfully, i want the normal proccess of magento that is save the order and redirect to success page, until now, i redirect to the bank page, but when the bank redirects me back to my web, i get an error of magento thats just say
**There was an error processing your order. Please contact us or try again later.**
so, what can i do here to solve my situation?? any help

Comment: Try this Link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728654/magento-redirect-checkout-payment-to-a-3rd-party-gateway?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

Ok, correct me if I'm wrong. You are sending customers to a banking page to make payments and then sending them back to your magento site to save their data and possibly show them the success page?